Integrating $\int_{0}^{1}\left[[x]+\left[x^{2}+3x+2\right]\right]dx$, where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function
I am facing problem in evaluating this integral. Please help me out:

How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}\left[[x]+\left[x^{2}+3x+2\right]\right]dx$$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function?

My way:
I applied one trick here. The trick is that we know that $$\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx$$ is $1$.
Now I tried to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+3x+2]dx$$. If we clearly notice then the value of $[x^{2}+3x+2]$ is $2$ at $x=0$. And at $x=1$ the value of $[x^{2}+3x+2]$ is $6$.
Therefore we can easily say that we have to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+3x+2]\mathrm dx$$ from the value $2$ to $6$.
Therefore the conditions are :
$2<x^{2}+3x+2<3$
$3<x^{2}+3x+2<4$
$4<x^{2}+3x+2<5$
$5<x^{2}+3x+2<6$
Therefore the integral will become:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}}[x^{2}+3x+2]dx +\int_{ \frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{17}-3}{2}}[x^{2}+3x+2]dx+\int_{ \frac{\sqrt{17}-3}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{21}-3}{2}}[x^{2}+3x+2]dx+ +\int_{ \frac{\sqrt{21}-3}{2}}^{1}[x^{2}+3x+2]dx$$
Now the final integral will be
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}}[1+2]dx+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{17}-3}{2}}[1+3]dx+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{17}-3}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{21}-3}{2}}[1+4]dx+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{21}-3}{2}}^{1}[1+5]dx$$
$1$ is coming here in all the possible cases because $$\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx$$ is $1$.
Therefore the final answer is $\frac{21-(\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{21})}{2}$
But Wolfram alpha is giving the answer to be $\frac{19-(\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{21})}{2}$
Please inform me that where I am wrong.

The greatest integer function $[x]$ is the greatest integer equal or smaller than $x$. It is the floor instead ceiling function (eg. $[0.5] = \lfloor 0.5 \rfloor = 0 \ne 1 = \lceil 0.5 \rceil$)

How do you know that $\int_0^1 [x] dx$ is $1$?

$\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx$ is zero, not 1.

@IIT Roorkee It seems all your questions stem from a lack of clarity with the G.I.F function. You should sit down and play around with the sketch of the G.I.F functions first as much as possible. The rest is pondering on the bounds/inequalities for the most part.

Sorry it was my mistake. I took into consideration $\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx=1$ which should be $0$ instead of $1$.

First remark that $x \mapsto x^2+3x +2$ is a strictly increasing function on $[0,1]$ so its image is equal to $[2,6]$ (the lower and upper bounds).
I denote "$[ \cdot ]$" as "$\lfloor \cdot \rfloor $". You have
$$ \lfloor x \rfloor=
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if} & x \in [0,1[ \\
1 & \text{if} & x = 1 \\
\end{cases}
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
\lfloor x^2+3x+2 \rfloor=
\begin{cases} 
2 & \text{if} & x \in \left[0,\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right[ \\
3 & \text{if} & x \in \left[\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right[ \\
4 & \text{if} & x \in \left[\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right[ \\
5 & \text{if} & x \in \left[\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2},1\right[ \\
6 & \text{if} & x = 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Thus we have
$$ \lfloor \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x^2+3x+2 \rfloor \rfloor =
\begin{cases} 
2 & \text{if} & x \in \left[0,\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right[ \\
3 & \text{if} & x \in \left[\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right[ \\
4 & \text{if} & x \in \left[\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right[ \\
5 & \text{if} & x \in \left[\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2},1\right[ \\
7 & \text{if} & x = 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
And finally
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \lfloor \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x^2+3x+2 \rfloor \rfloor \text{d}x = 2 \cdot \frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2} + 3 \left( \frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2} - \frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2} \right) + 4 \left( \frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2} - \frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2} \right) + 5 \left( 1 - \frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2} \right) + 7 \cdot 0$$
which is equal to
$$ \frac{19 - \sqrt{13} - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{21}}{2} $$

The mistake is that $\int_0^1[x]\,\mathrm dx$ is $0$ not $1$ since $[x]=0$ for $0\le x<1$.
Therefore, the given integral is just equal to
$$\int_0^1[x^2+3x+2]\,\mathrm dx$$
Note that $x^2+3x+2\in[2,6]$ for $x\in[0,1]$, so we break it into four parts as you say. Correcting this mistake should give you the correct answer.
Hope this helps. :)

You can verify your error through the following :
$$\int{[x]}\mathrm{d}x=x[x]-\frac12[x]\left(1+[x]\right)$$
So, $\int_0^1{[x]}\mathrm{d}x=1-\frac12\cdot1\cdot(1+1)=0$, which is not $1$.

(There is a word limit for comments, so I write it here as an explanation.)
What I mean is that the OP can verify (check) his own answer through the method I use here. When the OP found that his answer was different from that of Wolfram Alpha, and he didn't know that he was careless (or for some other reason?) and found that the value of $[x]$ on the entire interval $(0,1)$ was $1$ (or other ideas?), he could consider using the indefinite integral method here to recalculate (because the latter needs to consider the values ​​of the endpoints ($0$ and $1$), which is different from the first method) to confirm his mistakes. I think that when I check this kind of error, if I think that the value of $[x]$ on the entire interval $(0,1)$ is $1$ at the beginning (only using this idea), then it will be difficult for me to find this error (because I may think it ($[x]=1$) is obviously correct, so I won't think too much about it).
